# why should I use synchronized queue in producer/consumer problem

Tags: c++, multithreading

I do not see why the consumer & producer cannot access the same queue at the same time !
if the consumer will `pop ()` from the  head of the queue and if the producer `push()` in the back of the queue. I don't see any danger of using a normal queue in this case !

Comment: What is your question? What is the context of your statements? Please, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Just as a reminder though, many things revolve around guarantees. Something that can work still isn't necessarily guaranteed to work.

Comment: queue is shared state. All shared states (shared between threads) have to be synchronized to avoid race conditions.

Comment: imagine what happens when one calls `push()` and the other `pop()` at the same time while the queue is empty. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @MarekR but race condition occures when I do chack and act. if I don't -> no race condition !

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number what do u mean by "same time" here atomicity of CPU will do her job ! it will call one of them. if `push()` it will add an element and if `pop()` it will test is not queue is empty !

Comment: what "atomicity of CPU" ? I don't know all details of how a cpu works, but frankly, your mental image seems to be too simplistic. Neither `push` nor `pop` is a single instruction on your CPU. And even if it was, how about multi core cpus?

Comment: Are you perhaps imagining some queue implementation that guarantees that _pop()_ will never access the same memory that _push()_ does?

Comment: What queue class are you using? Read its documentation if it doesn't explicitly say its threadsafe then it isn't and you must take care of protecting the access to th queue.

Comment: `here atomicity of CPU will do her job`. Do not use statements which you do not understand. Modern CPU-s are optimized to do instruction out of order and there is also problem of synchronize low level memory cache and of course most of CPU have more then one cores so lots of things can be done at the same time. Looks like currently you have invalid mindset how multi-threading works, so until you will get rid of it, it will be hard to explain to you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @MarekR I'm not talking about multi-core... there are people instead of explaining and / or giving a solution they talk about mindset ...

Comment: All comments and answer are consistent and you've rejected all. This doesn't indicates that you will give us a chance to help you. Note your question is poor quality and to general (you didn't improve when it was point out), so do not complain that you receive general responses. It is best we could give you with current quality of question. It would be best if you just post whole code you have problem with, then someone will explain you line by line what should be fixed and why.

Answer (score 2):

Pushing and popping will change the internal state of the queue. The thread calling `push` may be pre-empted during the changes, meaning that the thread calling `pop` will see the queue in an invalid state.

If you're not using a thread-safe queue you can avoid this by locking around the calls, this serializing access to the queue. This means that if a thread is pre-empted whilst modifying the queue another thread will not be able to acquire the lock and modify the queue.